# Transposing a pandas DataFrame

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, transpose

My function is writing data into a `1x4 dataframe`, where each column (cell) is an array (`1x6544`). So, what I need to do is to transpose each of the inner array (`6544x1`) such that it is a nice `dataframe` of `6544x4` dimension.

How would I accomplish that?

Here's a sample of the output of the `dataframe`:

```
df = [(1,2,3,4),(a,b,c,d),(A,B,C,D,(0.25,0.655555,0.56,15.235)]
```

What I want like to see is this:

```
df1 = [1,a,A,0.25
       2,b,B,0.655555
       3,c,C,0.56
       4,d,D,15.235]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.transpose()` to transpose a DataFrame, and then `.to_numpy()` to get a NumPy array:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).transpose().to_numpy()
# or,
pd.DataFrame(data).T.to_numpy()
```

If you want the output as a 1D array, you need to reshape it:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).T.values.reshape(-1, )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = [('a','b','c','d'),('A','B','C','D'),(0.25,0.655555,0.56,15.235)]
>>> pd.DataFrame(data)
      0         1     2       3
0     a         b     c       d
1     A         B     C       D
2  0.25  0.655555  0.56  15.235
>>> pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
   0  1         2
0  a  A      0.25
1  b  B  0.655555
2  c  C      0.56
3  d  D    15.235
```